# how to derive overnight FX implied vol and how to translate into implied breakeven

Tags: implied-volatility, fxo

is there a good link or explanation how to get a specific day (next month's 1st trading day, etc) overnight implied vol? (pls guide where should i start with?)
and let say USDJPY (say forward ref is 135), overnight vol is 40%, how can i get the implied breakeven?
thanks.

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the use case for getting a forward ON IV in a month from today?

Comment: To bet/ understand on the cheapness/ expensiveness of a binary event?

Comment: What exactly would the bet look like? especially a bet based on some forward ON IV? Personally, I doubt there is much information content in a computed ON vol from existing quoted vols (or prices if listed FX options which generally aren't very liquid).